# Another word for the phenomenon of not remembering dreams

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word for the phenomenon due to which you are not able to remember dreams.

Example usage (in case the question is not clear) - 
Person A : The dream involved elephants, Megan Fox and a pole but I'm not able to recall it correctly...
Person B : Damn You "Phenomenon Name"!!!

Comment: ***Dreamnesia***, of course.

Comment: +1, would add to the Oxford English Dictionary again. Also I really wish I knew what kind of dream Person A was having...

Comment: _Disassociation_ comes to mind but is not specific to dreams...

Comment: +1 for dreamnesia. And it's almost legit... http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dreamnesia.

Comment: This article calls those kind of people "low recallers" as opposed to "high recallers": http://www.livescience.com/38856-why-people-recall-dreams.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Person B: Damn You, “Evanescence”!!!
>
> **evanescence** – noun
>   
>   **evanescent** – adjective
>   
>   **evanesce** – verb
>   
>   Soon passing out of sight, memory, or existence; quickly fading or
>   disappearing.
>   
>   [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/evanescent)

The term *evanescence* is indeed used in
[dream
 psychology](https://www.google.com/search?q=evanescence+dream+psychology)
(as well as in
[some musical
 pieces](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=evanescence+dream)):

> ... the dream's evanescence, the way in which, on awakening,
>   our thoughts thrust it aside ...
>   
>   [Sigmund Freud, *Dream
>      Psychology*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15489/15489-h/15489-h.htm)
>
> There are several established theories that help explain the evanescence of dreams.
>   
>   [Huffington Post, “Why Do We Have Trouble Remembering Our
>      Dreams?”](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/dreamscloud/remembering-dreams_b_8009552.html)